# Is it possibile to make a function from a generic Sub?

Tags: function, vba, excel

In my Excel worksheet a Button (Form Control) is present and the VBA code related to it is the following one:

```
Sub Import()

    Sheets("Import").Cells.ClearContents

    With Sheets("Import").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\...\my_file.csv" _
        , Destination:=Sheets("Import").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "my_file"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ticker = Sheets("Curve").Range("E1").Value
    tickerCorrected = Replace(ticker, " by", "")
    lastRow = Sheets("Import").Cells(Sheets("Import").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Sheets("Import").Range("B" & i).Value = tickerCorrected Then
            If Sheets("Import").Range("D" & i).Value = 0.5 Then
                Sheets("Curve").Range("K4:K11").Value = Sheets("Import").Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + 7).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Of course what the macro above does is not important, consider it just an example of something that usually you wouldn't assign to a function.

My attempt to make a function which executes the instructions above and returns a `Boolean`:

```
Public Function Importfn(ticker As String) As Boolean

    Sheets("Import").Cells.ClearContents

    With Sheets("Import").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\...\my_file.csv" _
        , Destination:=Sheets("Import").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "my_file"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ticker = Sheets("Curve").Range("E1").Value
    tickerCorrected = Replace(ticker, " by", "")
    lastRow = Sheets("Import").Cells(Sheets("Import").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Sheets("Import").Range("B" & i).Value = tickerCorrected Then
            If Sheets("Import").Range("D" & i).Value = 0.5 Then
                Sheets("Curve").Range("K4:K11").Value = Sheets("Import").Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + 7).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Importfn = True

End Function
```

That does not return anything but errors.

Questions:

1. is it actually possibile to make such a function?
2. Is there anything that you could do with a `Sub` assigned to a form and not within a function?
3. What should I amend in my function to make it work?

Comment: 1. how are you calling the function (via vba or worksheet?) 2. `That does not return anything but errors.`  What errors does it return?

Comment: 1. I call it from my worksheet with `=Import(E1)` in a generic cell.
2. `#VALUE!`

Comment: 1. You can't change other cells contents while calling a function from worksheet.

Comment: That seems a nice solution, but I am not familiar with that. Would you mind to expand your answer a little bit, please? Do you mean that, if I created a function like `Public Function CallFromSheet() call Import End Function`, I would actually be able to write `=CallFromSheet()` in any cell getting the same result as the form control?

Comment: You can, if you use the Worksheet_calculate sheet object event. I don't see a clear reason why you would do this with a formula though.

Comment: 1) Generally speaking, No you cannot manipulate worksheet objects from a worksheet function.  2) Yes, make it a Subroutine instead of a Function, attach the subroutine to a Shape, Form Control, or Worksheet event handler and invoke it that way. 3) What seems to be the problem?